# How to install dependencies that are installed in a tox-docker container, but NOT locally?

Tags: python, docker, macos, tox

I'd like to execute unit test (configured in `tox.ini`) in a docker container using [tox-docker](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox-docker) plugin. The idea behind it is to be able run unit tests, that require `cuda-python` module, on a MacBook with Apple M2 Pro.
My question is - how should I configure a corresponding section in a `tox.ini` so that the requirements are installed in a docker container, but not locally (because this would fail)?

Here is mentioned section in a `tox.ini`:

```
[testenv:test-docker-env]
docker =
    py-3.11
skip_install = false
deps =
    # -r{toxinidir}/requirements/requirements.txt     # <- this fails when executed locally on MacBook!
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements/requirements-test.txt
commands =
    python -m pytest --cov=src \
        --cov-report term-missing \
        --cov-report xml:coverage-reports/coverage-BUILD_{env:BUILD_NUMBER:0}.xml \
        --junitxml=xunit-reports/xunit-result-BUILD_{env:BUILD_NUMBER:0}.xml \
        -vv \
        tests/

[docker:py-3.11]
image = python:3.11
```

How can i instruct `tox-docker` to install required modules from the `{toxinidir}/requirements/requirements.txt`, but not let `tox` to install them locally?

Comment: I think you need to remove non-local dependencies from `tox.ini` and install them in a `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @phd, thank you for the hint! Would you like to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe a plugin could instruct `tox` to install some dependencies but not other; `tox` just installs locally whatever it sees in `tox.ini`. So I think you need to remove non-local dependencies from `tox.ini` and install them in a `Dockerfile`.